# Mysterious error message "The port 'COM1' does not exist"

Tags: c#, serial-port

I am getting the following error message when trying to access devices connected by USB port.

> The port 'COM1' does not exist

By looking into device manager, I am certain that the device has been assigned COM1 and no other device is attached to COM1. Why would this behavior occur?

Is this environment dependent, because the same version of the App doesn't produce this message when executed in a different system.

Comment: I think we can't say much without you showing us, which code you are using to access the device.

Comment: I understand your point, but as I mentioned in the post, it doesn't happen in every system. That is why I was wondering if this was an environment issue.

Comment: Is there no way to query the USB device and check which COM port it's been assigned? I've had to enter the COM port number myself for old mobile phones etc. and it always seemed like a nasty hack to me.

Comment: @Rup: The port number is being manually set to COM1. The app is written such a way that it actually looks into device signature and determines which port it's assigned to. Therefore, I wouldn't suspect incorrect port number

Comment: Does it work fine in hyperterminal (or equivalent)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My case is a very specific one.

What was happening is, there was a device that was previously connected. When it's removed, the Object making the connection was still holding on to the port. Now, when a new device was inserted, although a search for that device revealed that it was in COM1, but trying to open it caused this exception as the previous and still live object was holding on to the port.

Comment: Just wanted to add to this... I'm developing survey software for Trimble handheld devices that talk to survey transit units over serial. My stuff had been working then all of the sudden I was getting "COM1: does not exist" errors. Turns out the device had previously been used and some long ago opened but still in memory,  piece of native Trimble software (their general software suite for that device type) was holding on to that port. Soon as I terminated the process in Task Manager mine worked just fine,

Comment: @BikeMrown: I understand the issue occurs due to Processes/Threads holding on to the COM Device. I read somewhere, this sometimes occurs due to faults in the Device Driver itself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently i don't know what exactly .Net wants, but back in the old C/C++ days you had to open `COM1:` (take care for the colon after the port name).

Comment: The port naming isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Source: [MsdnLink](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ecd6f083-b189-448f-be91-0cff0099b84b/the-port-com1-does-not-exist?forum=csharpgeneral)

I figured out problem and answer. We need to get name of the port where drivers for Arduino is installed on your machine. Not all Arduino is getting installed on 'COM1' port. My Arduino Mega 2560 R3 was installed on port, 'COM3'

Paste the code in C# Main() function,

```
var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM3", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
 try
 {
     while (true)
     {
         serialPort.ReadTimeout = 2000;
         if (!serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Open();
         int readData = serialPort.ReadByte();
         Console.Write((char)readData);
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)  // Press CTRL-C to exit.
 {
     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
     Console.ReadKey();
 }
 serialPort.Close();
```

**Steps to find the port name:**

1. Start > Run > devmgmt.msc
2. Expand the node called, 'Port (COM & LPT)'
3. You find the name of the port for your Arduino device.

Comment: I'd guess you could find the port automatically from WMI? e.g. [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19840811/243245) - look at the GUIDs or properties of the Arduino if you know which one it is and query for those.

Comment: @Rup, thanks for additional way using WMI! I found the port name by using control panel (devmgmt.msc) and I read the serial data from my c# console application as well. Thanks again for your solution!