# Substring to get 3 characters from the last character vb.net

Tags: string, vb.net

i have the following string "USB SERIAL PORT (COM6)" i want to get COM6 out of this.

This is the code i am trying to use

```
string.substring(3, string.length - 1)
```

something of that sort. Havent been able to get anything.

Comment: Study the docs for [substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) and get simple examples working. You should always do this, don't just guess. In particular, why would startIndex be 3?!

Comment: @AndyG Okay, should i find the index of the brackets and then work from there?

Comment: Yes! You will at least get more of a response if you demonstrate such efforts.

Comment: @AndyG I got it,,, Thanks for the constructive criticism :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19840811/1070452  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix i am past that step :) Thanks tho.. I already have the names just trying to find the substring. I actually wanted the manufacturer information for each port...

Comment: No, you skipped some steps

Comment: @Plutonix Okay Sir. Also i have asked a couple of questions prior to this, I was just exhausted and wanted an easy answer.I think i am good with the tour and How to Ask( I appreciate you looking out for me though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd be better off using the last occurrence of `(` as an index, in case one day your string changes format, or com6 is longer (com10):

```
Dim lastBra as Integer = myString.LastIndexOf("("c)
Dim lastKet as Integer = myString.LastIndexOf(")"c)

Dim subs as String = myString.Substring(lastBra + 1, lastKet - lastBra - 1)
```

It's lastBra+1 because we want the character after the open bracket as a start. The length to substring is the bracket indexes, less one because we don't want the last bracket to be included:

[image]

Comment: Change the last line to `myString.Substring(lastBra + 1, lastKet - lastBra)`

Comment: I disagree, see the edited in screenshot. For a string of `abc(def)` lastBra would be 4, lastKet would be 8, we want the string from 5, length 3, but your suggestion of lastKet - lastBra is 8-4, which is 4, not 3 (assuming VB is in 1 based index mode. If it's in 0 based index mode all these numbers change by 1, but the overall math is the same)

Comment: Yes! I am sorry i was adding +1 to lastBra itself

Comment: It's good to challenge, made me double check and deliver a better answer I think, thanks!